# psexec to read contents of file

Tags: windows, psexec

I am trying to do a simple task.  Use PsExec to read a file's contents.

I have tried:

```
psexec \\<system> cmd "type C:\file.txt"
```

Running the command locally on the machine works fine... but with psexec it connects, starts psexec remotely .. then exits with no output.

heres the output:

```
PsExec v2.0 - Execute processes remotely
Copyright (C) 2001-2013 Mark Russinovich
Sysinternals - www.sysinternals.com


Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7601]
Copyright (c) 2009 Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.
```

I have tried searching for people trying to do the same thing but haven't had any luck.

Any suggestions?  They will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `type` is a built-in command, not an executable.  Try `psexec \\system cmd /c type c:\file.txt`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Harry answered my question in a comment.

"type is a built-in command, not an executable"..

This worked:

```
psexec \\<system> cmd /c "type C:\file.txt"
```